# If-elif-else statement not working in simple Python 3.3 class?

Tags: python, if-statement, python-3.x

My code is:

```
def nameAndConfirm():
    global name,confirm
    print("What is your name? ")
    name = input()
    str(name)
    print("Is",name,"correct? ")
    confirm = input()
    str(confirm) 
    print(confirm)

    if confirm.upper() == "Y" or "YES":
        classSelection()
    elif confirm.upper() == "N" or "NO":
        nameAndConfirm()
    else:
        print("Valid answers are Y/Yes or N/No!")
        nameAndConfirm()

nameAndConfirm()
```

Critique on this code would be nice as well. I know its very shifty, I know how to make it shorter in some ways but I was trying to get my if-elif-else to work. I have no clue what else I can do as I've tried everything I know. Also I made an indent 4 spaces in the above code. **Edit: sorry the error is that it always runs the "if" it never goes past the first if line no matter what you enter in for confirm

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The condition `confirm.upper() == "Y" or "YES"` and the other one are not evaluated as you expect. You want

```
confirm.upper() in {"Y", "YES"}
```

or

```
confirm.upper() == "Y" or confirm.upper() == "YES"
```

Your condition is equivalent to:

```
(confirm.upper() == "Y") or "YES"
```

which is always truthy:

```
In [1]: True or "Yes"
Out[1]: True

In [2]: False or "Yes"
Out[2]: 'Yes'
```

---

On a separate note, the lines

```
str(name)
```

and

```
str(confirm)
```

don't do anything. The values returned by the functions are not saved anywhere, and `name` and `confirm` are not altered. Moreover, they are already strings to begin with, because they hold the return values of `input()`.

Comment: Not that it really makes any difference with two elements, but sets are more suitable for membership testing, `{"Y", "YES"}`

Comment: @GP89 Agreed, I use them in such cases, too. Edited

Comment: Ah okay thank you! I haven't coded in Python in a year and that is something I used to know, but forgot.